# Sudden Tensorflow / Keras Google Colab dependency problems `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

I have running a machine learning model (Matterport's Mask R-CNN) in google colab for a couple of weeks.  All of a sudden today I am unable to run any of my notebooks due to I think some kind of dependency mismatch error.  The full error is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d76d39ae81e5> in <module>()
     11 
     12 import tensorflow as tf
---> 13 import keras
     14 import platform
     15 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py in <module>()
     23 from .np_utils import to_categorical
     24 from .np_utils import normalize
---> 25 from .multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py in <module>()
      5 from __future__ import print_function
      6 
----> 7 from ..layers.merge import concatenate
      8 from .. import backend as K
      9 from ..layers.core import Lambda

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 from ..utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
----> 4 from ..engine import Layer
      5 from ..engine import Input
      6 from ..engine import InputLayer

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 # note: topology.Node is an internal class,
      2 # it isn't meant to be used by Keras users.
----> 3 from .topology import InputSpec
      4 from .topology import Input
      5 from .topology import InputLayer

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 from .. import backend as K
---> 18 from .. import initializers
     19 from ..utils.io_utils import ask_to_proceed_with_overwrite
     20 from ..utils.layer_utils import print_summary as print_layer_summary

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py in <module>()
    122 # from ALL_OBJECTS. We make no guarantees as to whether these objects will
    123 # using their correct version.
--> 124 populate_deserializable_objects()
    125 globals().update(LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS)
    126 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/initializers/__init__.py in populate_deserializable_objects()
     47 
     48   LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS = {}
---> 49   LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
     50 
     51   # Compatibility aliases (need to exist in both V1 and V2).

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.7/tensorflow_core/python/util/module_wrapper.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    191   def __getattr__(self, name):
    192     try:
--> 193       attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
    194     except AttributeError:
    195       if not self._tfmw_public_apis:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v2' has no attribute '__internal__'
```

the pip list of my installed dependency versions is:

```
Package                       Version            
----------------------------- -------------------
absl-py                       0.12.0             
alabaster                     0.7.12             
albumentations                0.1.12             
altair                        4.1.0              
appdirs                       1.4.4              
argon2-cffi                   20.1.0             
arviz                         0.11.2             
astor                         0.8.1              
astropy                       4.2.1              
astunparse                    1.6.3              
async-generator               1.10               
atari-py                      0.2.9              
atomicwrites                  1.4.0              
attrs                         21.2.0             
audioread                     2.1.9              
autograd                      1.3                
Babel                         2.9.1              
backcall                      0.2.0              
backports.tempfile            1.0                
backports.weakref             1.0.post1          
beautifulsoup4                4.6.3              
bleach                        3.3.0              
blis                          0.4.1              
bokeh                         2.3.2              
Bottleneck                    1.3.2              
branca                        0.4.2              
bs4                           0.0.1              
bz2file                       0.98               
CacheControl                  0.12.6             
cached-property               1.5.2              
cachetools                    4.2.2              
catalogue                     1.0.0              
certifi                       2020.12.5          
cffi                          1.14.5             
cftime                        1.5.0              
chainer                       7.4.0              
chardet                       3.0.4              
click                         7.1.2              
cloudpickle                   1.3.0              
cmake                         3.12.0             
cmdstanpy                     0.9.5              
colorcet                      2.0.6              
colorlover                    0.3.0              
community                     1.0.0b1            
contextlib2                   0.5.5              
convertdate                   2.3.2              
coverage                      3.7.1              
coveralls                     0.5                
crcmod                        1.7                
cufflinks                     0.17.3             
cupy-cuda101                  7.4.0              
cvxopt                        1.2.6              
cvxpy                         1.0.31             
cycler                        0.10.0             
cymem                         2.0.5              
Cython                        0.29.23            
daft                          0.0.4              
dask                          2.12.0             
datascience                   0.10.6             
debugpy                       1.0.0              
decorator                     4.4.2              
defusedxml                    0.7.1              
descartes                     1.1.0              
dill                          0.3.3              
distributed                   1.25.3             
dlib                          19.18.0            
dm-sonnet                     1.35               
dm-tree                       0.1.6              
docopt                        0.6.2              
docutils                      0.17.1             
dopamine-rl                   1.0.5              
earthengine-api               0.1.266            
easydict                      1.9                
ecos                          2.0.7.post1        
editdistance                  0.5.3              
en-core-web-sm                2.2.5              
entrypoints                   0.3                
ephem                         3.7.7.1            
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0              
fa2                           0.3.5              
fastai                        1.0.61             
fastdtw                       0.3.4              
fastprogress                  1.0.0              
fastrlock                     0.6                
fbprophet                     0.7.1              
feather-format                0.4.1              
filelock                      3.0.12             
firebase-admin                4.4.0              
fix-yahoo-finance             0.0.22             
Flask                         1.1.4              
flatbuffers                   1.12               
folium                        0.8.3              
future                        0.16.0             
gast                          0.2.2              
GDAL                          2.2.2              
gdown                         3.6.4              
gensim                        3.6.0              
geographiclib                 1.50               
geopy                         1.17.0             
gevent                        1.4.0              
gin-config                    0.4.0              
glob2                         0.7                
google                        2.0.3              
google-api-core               1.26.3             
google-api-python-client      1.12.8             
google-auth                   1.30.0             
google-auth-httplib2          0.0.4              
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.4              
google-cloud-bigquery         1.21.0             
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 1.1.0              
google-cloud-core             1.0.3              
google-cloud-datastore        1.8.0              
google-cloud-firestore        1.7.0              
google-cloud-language         1.2.0              
google-cloud-storage          1.18.1             
google-cloud-translate        1.5.0              
google-colab                  1.0.0              
google-pasta                  0.2.0              
google-resumable-media        0.4.1              
googleapis-common-protos      1.53.0             
googledrivedownloader         0.4                
graph-nets                    1.0.5              
graphviz                      0.10.1             
greenlet                      0.4.15             
grpcio                        1.34.1             
gspread                       3.0.1              
gspread-dataframe             3.0.8              
gunicorn                      20.0.4             
gym                           0.17.3             
h5py                          3.1.0              
HeapDict                      1.0.1              
hijri-converter               2.1.1              
holidays                      0.10.5.2           
holoviews                     1.14.3             
html5lib                      1.0.1              
httpimport                    0.5.18             
httplib2                      0.17.4             
httplib2shim                  0.0.3              
humanize                      0.5.1              
hyperopt                      0.1.2              
ideep4py                      2.0.0.post3        
idna                          2.10               
imageio                       2.4.1              
imagesize                     1.2.0              
imbalanced-learn              0.4.3              
imblearn                      0.0                
imgaug                        0.2.9              
importlib-metadata            4.0.1              
importlib-resources           5.1.3              
imutils                       0.5.4              
inflect                       2.1.0              
iniconfig                     1.1.1              
install                       1.3.4              
intel-openmp                  2021.2.0           
intervaltree                  2.1.0              
ipykernel                     4.10.1             
ipyparallel                   6.3.0              
ipython                       5.5.0              
ipython-genutils              0.2.0              
ipython-sql                   0.3.9              
ipywidgets                    7.6.3              
itsdangerous                  1.1.0              
jax                           0.2.13             
jaxlib                        0.1.66+cuda110     
jdcal                         1.4.1              
jedi                          0.18.0             
jieba                         0.42.1             
Jinja2                        2.11.3             
joblib                        1.0.1              
jpeg4py                       0.1.4              
jsonschema                    2.6.0              
jupyter                       1.0.0              
jupyter-client                5.3.5              
jupyter-console               5.2.0              
jupyter-core                  4.7.1              
jupyterlab-pygments           0.1.2              
jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.0              
kaggle                        1.5.12             
kapre                         0.3.5              
Keras                         2.1.5              
Keras-Applications            1.0.8              
keras-nightly                 2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2              
keras-vis                     0.4.1              
kfac                          0.2.0              
kiwisolver                    1.3.1              
korean-lunar-calendar         0.2.1              
librosa                       0.8.0              
lightgbm                      2.2.3              
llvmlite                      0.34.0             
lmdb                          0.99               
lucid                         0.3.10             
LunarCalendar                 0.0.9              
lxml                          4.2.6              
magenta                       0.3.19             
Markdown                      3.3.4              
MarkupSafe                    2.0.1              
mask-rcnn                     2.1                
matplotlib                    3.2.2              
matplotlib-inline             0.1.2              
matplotlib-venn               0.11.6             
mesh-tensorflow               0.1.12             
mido                          1.2.6              
mir-eval                      0.5                
missingno                     0.4.2              
mistune                       0.8.4              
mizani                        0.6.0              
mkl                           2019.0             
mlxtend                       0.14.0             
more-itertools                8.7.0              
moviepy                       0.2.3.5            
mpi4py                        3.0.3              
mpmath                        1.2.1              
msgpack                       1.0.2              
multiprocess                  0.70.11.1          
multitasking                  0.0.9              
murmurhash                    1.0.5              
music21                       5.5.0              
natsort                       5.5.0              
nbclient                      0.5.3              
nbconvert                     5.6.1              
nbformat                      5.1.3              
nest-asyncio                  1.5.1              
netCDF4                       1.5.6              
networkx                      2.5.1              
nibabel                       3.0.2              
nltk                          3.2.5              
nose                          1.3.7              
notebook                      5.3.1              
numba                         0.51.2             
numexpr                       2.7.3              
numpy                         1.19.5             
nvidia-ml-py3                 7.352.0            
oauth2client                  4.1.3              
oauthlib                      3.1.0              
okgrade                       0.4.3              
opencv-contrib-python         4.1.2.30           
opencv-python                 4.1.2.30           
openpyxl                      2.5.9              
opt-einsum                    3.3.0              
osqp                          0.6.2.post0        
packaging                     20.9               
palettable                    3.3.0              
pandas                        1.1.5              
pandas-datareader             0.9.0              
pandas-gbq                    0.13.3             
pandas-profiling              1.4.1              
pandocfilters                 1.4.3              
panel                         0.11.3             
param                         1.10.1             
parso                         0.8.2              
pathlib                       1.0.1              
patsy                         0.5.1              
pexpect                       4.8.0              
pickleshare                   0.7.5              
Pillow                        7.1.2              
pip                           19.3.1             
pip-tools                     4.5.1              
plac                          1.1.3              
plotly                        4.4.1              
plotnine                      0.6.0              
pluggy                        0.7.1              
pooch                         1.3.0              
portpicker                    1.3.9              
prefetch-generator            1.0.1              
preshed                       3.0.5              
pretty-midi                   0.2.8              
prettytable                   2.1.0              
progressbar2                  3.38.0             
prometheus-client             0.10.1             
promise                       2.3                
prompt-toolkit                1.0.18             
protobuf                      3.12.4             
psutil                        5.4.8              
psycopg2                      2.7.6.1            
ptyprocess                    0.7.0              
py                            1.10.0             
pyarrow                       3.0.0              
pyasn1                        0.4.8              
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8              
pycocotools                   2.0.2              
pycparser                     2.20               
pyct                          0.4.8              
pydata-google-auth            1.2.0              
pydot                         1.3.0              
pydot-ng                      2.0.0              
pydotplus                     2.0.2              
PyDrive                       1.3.1              
pyemd                         0.5.1              
pyerfa                        2.0.0              
pyglet                        1.5.0              
Pygments                      2.6.1              
pygobject                     3.26.1             
pymc3                         3.11.2             
PyMeeus                       0.5.11             
pymongo                       3.11.4             
pymystem3                     0.2.0              
PyOpenGL                      3.1.5              
pyparsing                     2.4.7              
pypng                         0.0.20             
pyrsistent                    0.17.3             
pysndfile                     1.3.8              
PySocks                       1.7.1              
pystan                        2.19.1.1           
pytest                        3.6.4              
python-apt                    0.0.0              
python-chess                  0.23.11            
python-dateutil               2.8.1              
python-louvain                0.15               
python-rtmidi                 1.4.0              
python-slugify                5.0.2              
python-utils                  2.5.6              
pytz                          2018.9             
pyviz-comms                   2.0.1              
PyWavelets                    1.1.1              
PyYAML                        3.13               
pyzmq                         22.0.3             
qdldl                         0.1.5.post0        
qtconsole                     5.1.0              
QtPy                          1.9.0              
regex                         2019.12.20         
requests                      2.23.0             
requests-oauthlib             1.3.0              
resampy                       0.2.2              
retrying                      1.3.3              
rpy2                          3.4.4              
rsa                           4.7.2              
scikit-image                  0.16.2             
scikit-learn                  0.22.2.post1       
scipy                         1.4.1              
screen-resolution-extra       0.0.0              
scs                           2.1.3              
seaborn                       0.11.1             
semantic-version              2.8.4              
semver                        2.13.0             
Send2Trash                    1.5.0              
setuptools                    56.1.0             
setuptools-git                1.2                
Shapely                       1.7.1              
simplegeneric                 0.8.1              
six                           1.15.0             
sklearn                       0.0                
sklearn-pandas                1.8.0              
smart-open                    5.0.0              
snowballstemmer               2.1.0              
sortedcontainers              2.4.0              
SoundFile                     0.10.3.post1       
spacy                         2.2.4              
Sphinx                        1.8.5              
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4              
sphinxcontrib-websupport      1.2.4              
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.15             
sqlparse                      0.4.1              
srsly                         1.0.5              
stable-baselines              2.2.1              
statsmodels                   0.10.2             
sympy                         1.7.1              
tables                        3.4.4              
tabulate                      0.8.9              
tblib                         1.7.0              
tensor2tensor                 1.14.1             
tensorboard                   1.15.0             
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1              
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.0              
tensorflow                    1.15.2             
tensorflow-datasets           4.0.1              
tensorflow-estimator          1.15.1             
tensorflow-gan                2.0.0              
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.5.0              
tensorflow-hub                0.12.0             
tensorflow-metadata           1.0.0              
tensorflow-probability        0.7.0              
termcolor                     1.1.0              
terminado                     0.10.0             
testpath                      0.5.0              
text-unidecode                1.3                
textblob                      0.15.3             
tflearn                       0.3.2              
Theano-PyMC                   1.1.2              
thinc                         7.4.0              
tifffile                      2021.4.8           
toml                          0.10.2             
toolz                         0.11.1             
torch                         1.8.1+cu101        
torchsummary                  1.5.1              
torchtext                     0.9.1              
torchvision                   0.9.1+cu101        
tornado                       5.1.1              
tqdm                          4.41.1             
traitlets                     5.0.5              
tweepy                        3.10.0             
typeguard                     2.7.1              
typing-extensions             3.7.4.3            
tzlocal                       1.5.1              
uritemplate                   3.0.1              
urllib3                       1.24.3             
vega-datasets                 0.9.0              
wasabi                        0.8.2              
wcwidth                       0.2.5              
webencodings                  0.5.1              
Werkzeug                      1.0.1              
wheel                         0.36.2             
widgetsnbextension            3.5.1              
wordcloud                     1.5.0              
wrapt                         1.12.1             
xarray                        0.18.2             
xgboost                       0.90               
xkit                          0.0.0              
xlrd                          1.1.0              
xlwt                          1.3.0              
yellowbrick                   0.9.1              
zict                          2.0.0              
zipp                          3.4.1              
zmq                           0.0.0
```

How can I get my environment working again?

Comment: was there a need not to be current? i mean you are using tensor flow - 1.15.2 and Keras - 2.1.5 , while now they are at 2.5.0.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem when I try to :

```
!pip uninstall keras-nightly
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
```

and then install tensorflow and kerass with version you want to use

Comment: Thanks!, May be you also need `!pip install h5py==2.8`

Comment: perfect. this was the solution for me

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue myself and I am also using Matterport's Mask-RCNN and google colab. The way I fixed it for my case is by installing the following versions of keras and tensorflow and restarting the runtime:

!pip install keras==2.3.0
!pip install tensorflow==1.15.0rc2

I hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip uninstall keras-nightly
!pip install h5py==2.10.0
```

I added this to the top of my code and the problem is now solved. I suspect that this issue was caused by the recent update for keras-nightly.